# Re-Initializing a const char array in C is not giving error

Tags: c, arrays, string, initialization, constants

While initializing a const char array, I tried to change the string and I was able to change it without any issue.

I was learning how to initialize a const char array.
I think I am doing some mistake here which I am not able to find.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    const char *strs[10];
    strs[0] = "wwww.google.com";
    printf("%s\n", strs[0]);
    strs[1] = "https://wwww.google.com";
    strs[0] = "ss";
    printf("%s\n", strs[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> 1st init: wwww.google.com
>   2nd init: ss  -> Here, I expect it to throw error

Comment: The pointers you’re setting (not initializing) are not constant; the data they point at can’t be modified via the pointers, though.  You don’t try to modify the strings; all is well.

Comment: If the pointers were constant, your assignments would generate compiler warnings.

Comment: `1st init`. Nah, the pointers are default initialized first. And then you assign for a second time with `"wwww.google.com"`.

Comment: `const char *strs[10];` defines `strs` as an array of ten pointers to constant characters. The array itself isn't constant, and neither is it an array of characters.

Comment: Incidentally, those are assignments, not reinitializations. Initialization is something that happens when an object is created, and you cannot do it more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const char* s = "Hi";
```

tells the compiler that the *content* that the pointer points to is constant. This means that `s[0] = 'P';` will result in a compilation error. But you can modify the pointer. On the other hand,

```
char* const s = "Hi";
```

tells the compiler that that the pointer is constant. This means that `s = "Pi";` will result in a compilation error. But no compilation error will be thrown when you try to modify the string<sup>*</sup>

Your code depicts the former behaviour, not the latter as you seem to have thought

---

<sup>* Modifying string literals will invoke Undefined Behaviour</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
const char *strs[10];
```

`strs` is an array of 10 pointers to `const char`. You can change the pointers; you cannot change the chars

```
strs[2] = NULL; // ok: change the pointer
strs[0][0] = '#'; // wrong; cannot change the char
```

Maybe try

```
const char * const strs[10] = {"www.google.com",
                               "https://www.google.com",
                               "www.google.com/",
                               "https://www.google.com/",
                               NULL, NULL };
```

which makes `strs` an array of 10 **read-only** pointers to `const char`. You cannot change the pointers after initialization.

Answer (score 0):

To put this in simple English(not necessarily 100% accurate but serves to conceptualise), this

```
const char *strs[10];
```

initialises a contant array **strs** which contains none constant elements. Thus, the elements in the array can be changed but the array itself cannot be changed